# Jplayer not working correctly

Tags: php, jquery, smarty, jplayer

I have foreach smarty

```
{foreach from=$listFeature item=item}
```

and this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_{$item.id_product}",
            {
                mp3: "download/{$item.audio_link}",
                oga: "download/{$item.audio_link}"
            }, {
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_{$item.id_product}"
            });

        });
        </script>
```

also:

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_{$item.id_product}" class="cp-jplayer"></div>
```

but it's not working correctly,audio played for 5-6 elements, and other js code on site is not working correctly.
p.s sorry for my english

Comment: 'not working' isn't a useful description. Set some breakpoints, step through your code. Show us the rendered output, since that's what JS will be seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding {literal}-blocks to avoid smarty getting confused with JavaScript syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_{/literal}{$item.id_product}{literal}",
  {
  {/literal}
    mp3: "download/{$item.audio_link}",
    oga: "download/{$item.audio_link}"
  {literal}
  }, {
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_{/literal}{$item.id_product}{literal}"
  });
});
{/literal}
</script>
```

Comment: it does not work :( Maybe It is conflict of js scripts ?

Comment: I don't get any errors in debug panel, but my other js scipts is not working

Comment: What are you trying to do? play the 6 songs in a queue? This would not work with your foreach-loop. It would rather try to create 6 players at the same time. I do not know CirclePlayer, but does it have an option where you can pass an array of filenames, you like to play. If so, you should pass the filenames in there, rather than creating the whole CirclePlayer()-object 6 times.

Comment: I need to create 12 CirclePlayers on page with their links on mp3 file

Comment: You very rarely need to use `{literal}` any more - just make sure your Javascript always has a space after an opening `{` and JS and Smarty will get along fine.